# obtener dos campos de un json para mostrarlo en un solo

Tags: json

El servicio me devuelve:

`"precios": [ { "precio": "500.00", "codproducto": "M", "tipocliente": "1", "abrevproducto": "Botellon 12 Lts" }, { "precio": "600.00", "codproducto": "N", "tipocliente": "1", "abrevproducto": "Botellon 20 lts"`

Todo este json lo estoy guardando en un atributo llamado "lista precio"

y lo que necesito guardar en dos distintas, precio botellon 12 lts (con el codigo de cliente N) y precio botellon 20 lts (codigo producto N) para mostrarlos por separados.

Estoy usando este codigo, pero se que no es correcto

```
var x = attributeApi.get('listaprecio');

attributeApi.set('precio',x[0].precio);
attributeApi.set('codproducto',x[0].codproducto);

attributeApi.set('precioycod');
```

Gracias

La idea es que yo pueda mostrar: El precio del botellon de 20lts es = (respuesta)

Answer (score 1):

O sea, ¿más o menos esto?

```js
listaprecio = {
  "precios": [{
    "precio": "500.00",
    "codproducto": "M",
    "tipocliente": "1",
    "abrevproducto": "Botellon 12 Lts"
  }, {
    "precio": "600.00",
    "codproducto": "N",
    "tipocliente": "1",
    "abrevproducto": "Botellon 20 lts"
  }]
}

for (var x of listaprecio.precios) {
  console.log("El precio del " + x.abrevproducto + " es = " + x.precio)
}
```